# TFS - Reopen closed merge window

Tags: tfs

In TFS 2010 ran`tf merge /recursive /baseless` which opened the merge window. After merging many files (some kept source, some kept target, some manually merged), accidentally hit the ESC button & the merge window was closed. Is there a way to reopen the merge window & continue from the point before the window close?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you closed resolve window. You can reopen it with "tf resolve". You can see all pending changes in ui with " tf checkin" just don't press the button :)